# Getting a Youtube video title using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having trouble with getting a youtube video title using AngularJS

Here's the code I have so far:

services.js

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

    myServices.factory('ytapi', ['$resource',
      function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gzDS-Kfd5XQ?alt=json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&prettyprint=true&fields=title', {}, {
          jsonp_query: {
            method: 'JSONP'
          }
        });
      }
    ]);
```

controllers.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myServices']);

    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'ytapi', 
      function($scope, ytapi) {
        $scope.feeds = ytapi.jsonp_query();
        console.log()
    }]);
```

What I don't know how can I parse the data so I could show the title of the video alone instead of the whole JSON.

Comment: I've used your code to make a working example
http://plnkr.co/edit/ElWctwROCR9wdJB4KEIB?p=preview

Comment: @maurycy,@user3703693 thanks for the example!  Could you explain a bit more how it works for a angular newbie?  I am curious to see how I might be able to pass a youTube ID from the controller.  I'm afraid I don't totally understand how this code is working!